# How to write PHP code inside blade template

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel blade template, I have a table in which I want to add another column
after this code

```
<td>{{format_price($mission->amount)}}</td>
```

**I added this :**

```
    @php
        $amount_to_be_collected = DB::table('shipments')
        ->select('amount_to_be_collected')
        ->where('mission_id', $mission->id)
        ->get();
    @endphp

<td>{{format_price($amount_to_be_collected)}}</td>
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: @groovy_guy there is no difference (sql injection wise) between a code in the blade and one in the controller. both are server side (if that is what you though of).

Comment: `$amount_to_be_collected` is collection.

Comment: @Abdelouahad Elfihri it would be better if your mention problem you facing error anything?

Comment: @groovy_guy it still not open to SQL injection since he is using the eloquent query builder and not a raw statement. Being in the blade or the controller has nothing to do with this type of vulnerabilities

Comment: AbdelouahadElfihri N69S's answer below should solve your query
@N69S Thanks for the info but someone told me earlier that it's not good to use `@php --- @endphp` in blade on one of my questions

Comment: @groovy_guy yeah, using `@php --- @endphp` is no good in the blade and putting a query in the blade is very bad. but nothing to do with SQL injection

Comment: @N69S ok thanks, it clears my confusion as well :)

Comment: i have 500 error when i use this code

Comment: Sure, Why not @N69S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, You should not put DB query code in your blade.

Now, when you run a query using eloquent and call `get()`, the response is a `Collection::class` instance that can be treated as an array but cannot be automatically transformed into a number/string.

If you only need the value of on field for one entry, use `value()` instead.

```
$amount_to_be_collected = DB::table('shipments')
    ->where('mission_id', $mission->id)
    ->value('amount_to_be_collected');
```

Comment: thanks millions times brother it works

Answer (score 0):

Note: It is not good to use db queries in blade views, you can also use helper

Try this before using DB facade you need to call this class in blade view [Running Database Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#running-database-queries)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Comment: Laravel has an alias for the DB facade on the root namespace, you can use `\DB` directly